# CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

[image]

As shown I have error in using DashboardBusiness;
I need an access class1.cs but I'm getting The type or namespace name could not be found.

Comment: what does class1.cs look like?  Are you *sure* it has a `DashboardBusiness` namespace?

Comment: Do those namespaces exist?  What happens when you simply delete those two lines of code?

Comment: Claies  yes it has DashboardBusiness namespace but let me give you another example , In login.aspx.cs i have error in using EmployeeSchedule._2___CLASS_OBJECT;  , and inside dashboardbusiness i have user.cs as below namespace EmployeeSchedule._2___CLASS_OBJECT
{
    public class User
    {
        private readonly int id;
        public int ID
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
        }

Comment: @MomenAlnaser: Please put code in the question, not in comments, for obvious readability reasons.  And rather than try to describe the structure of the code, show it.  Give a complete example of the code which produces the error.

Comment: ok I will edit to be more clear

Comment: David , if i delete them , i cann't access user.cs

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem in VS2017. I found the class just created is not in the project.(on the top of the code edit panel you can see the project this file in) Right click the solution and disable the lightweight solution load. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by adding required DLL files.

Answer (score -1):

### Its simple, concatenate Project name, Models and Models name with dot

- My Project name is WebApplication2
- My Class name is Class1 which is in Models folder

## using WebApplication2.Models;

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Models;
namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Class1 class1 = new Class1();
            return View();
        }
    }
```